# Expectation of hitting time of a markov chain

Tags: probability, markov-chains

Let $\{X_n\}$ be a homogenous Markov chain, taking values in N.

$T_i:=\inf\{k\ge0:X_k=i\}$ is the first time when the chain arrives at i. I know that if X is irreducible positive recurrent, then $E_iT_i$ is finite.

Now I want to know some results about $E_j T_i$, the expected time of first arrival at state $i$ starting from state $j$. I think that it should be finite almost surely.

Is there any explicit form of $E_j T_i$, or inequality? And what about an arbitrary initial distribution?   Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "discrete parameter"?

Comment: By $E_jT_i$ do you mean the expected time, starting from state $j$, to first arrive at state $i$?

Comment: discrete parameter means that the markov chain takes value in a discrete space. Or explicitly, in N={0,1,2,...}. And $E_jT_i$ means the expected time, starting from j, to first arrive at i. For any recurrent state i, we can compute $E_iT_i$ by construct its invarient measure, and I want to know is there any similar result about $E_jT_i$. Or for any positive recurrent chain, is $E_jT_i$ finite?

Comment: I have edited to reopen, but there is likely a problem with your defintion of $E_i T_i$ as the infimum of times when $X = i$ starting from $i$ is simply zero.  Therefore the finiteness of $E_i T_i$ would not depend on whether states are recurrent with positive probability.   Also, is "N" supposed to be the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$?  Any computation will require knowledge of the transition probabilitiies for these states.

Answer (score 10):

For a fixed $i$, let $\psi(j) = \mathbb{E}_j T_i$, i.e. the expected time to reach state $i$ starting from state $j$. Then for $\psi(j)$ the following holds:

$$
\psi(j) =
\begin{cases}
0\text{,} & j = i\\
1 + \sum\limits_{k \neq j} p_{j k}\psi(k)\text{,} & j \neq i
\end{cases}
$$

where $p_{j k}$ denotes the one-step transition probability from $j$ to $k$.

---

**Proof sketch** Start from state $j$. If $j = i$, then obviously $T_i = 0$, and so $\mathbb{E}_j[T_i \mid j = i] = 0$. If, however, $j \neq i$, then $T_i = 1 + T^{\prime}_i$, where $T^{\prime}_i$ denotes the remaining time to reach $i$. Invoking the Markov property conditional on the first step, and the chain's homogeneity, we can get the recurrence stated above.

---

You can generalize the above recurrence using an arbitrary award function depending on which state you end up in. Here, for example, the award function gives $1$ (you can count this $1$ as a penalty though) whenever $j \neq i$, and $0$ when $j = 0$.

---

Another way you can calculate this is by marking the state you want to reach as an *absorbing* one, and use the fundamental matrix to calculate the expected time until absorption. There is also a mean first passage matrix. See [Grinstead & Snell, pp. 461 onward](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~prob/prob/prob.pdf).

Comment: The formula is incorrect, the correct is $$\psi(j) =
\begin{cases}
0\text{,} & j = i\\
1 + \sum\limits_{\color{red}{k \neq i}} p_{j k}\psi(k)\text{,} & j \neq i
\end{cases}$$