# Why does this (markov chain related) system have a unique solution

Tags: linear-algebra, markov-chains

[Expectation of hitting time of a markov chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1307878/expectation-of-hitting-time-of-a-markov-chain)

In the question above we can find a system that allows us to calculate the expected time to hit a state $i$ , from every other state

$$
\psi(j) =
\begin{cases}
0\text{,} & j = i\\
1 + \sum\limits_{k \neq j} p_{j k}\psi(k)\text{,} & j \neq i
\end{cases}
$$

That it has a solution seems clear (the expected values respect all those equations)

Why is this solution unique?